# Form validation of a textbox and text area with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm doing an assignment and I've been working quite a while on it but I can't make heads or tales about how to even do this.

Text Box Edits

> The field should be edited to remove any occurrences of the three characters: /, \ or *. Identify the number of characters the user entered into the field and the number of characters remaining after the edit.

Text Area

> All blank spaces should be replaced with the + character. Remove all carriage returns and line feeds. Identify the number of characters entered into the textarea before and after the edit.

this is my HTML

```html
Put something in the textbox please
<br>
<form name = "TB">
<input type = "text" name = "tb" size = 30 maxlength = 30 value = " "> 
</form>
<br>
<span id="tx1">textbox value</span> <br>
<span id="tx2">texbox length</span> <br>
<span id="tx3">textbox replace value</span> <br>
<span id="tx4">texbox replace length</span> <br>
<br>
<br>
<form name = "TA">
<textarea name = "TA" rows = "5" cols =40>Default Value</textarea>
</form>
<br>
<br>

<input type = "button" value = "Edit and Report" onClick = "valthisform();">
```

I figured everything out.

```
var txbox = document.TX.tb.value;

tx1.innerHTML = txbox;
tx2.innerHTML = txbox.length;

var txbax = document.TX.tb.value;
var rep = txbax.replace(/\u002a|\u002c|\u005c|\u002f/gi, "");


tx3.innerHTML = rep;
tx4.innerHTML = rep.length;

var txar = document.TA.txx.value;

ta1.innerHTML = txar;
ta2.innerHTML = txar.length;

var txarr = document.TA.txx.value;
var repp = txarr.replace(/\u0020/gi, "+");

ta3.innerHTML = repp.replace(/\u000d|\u000a/gi, "");
ta4.innerHTML = ta3.innerHTML.length;
```

Comment: You should probably supply any examples of your script that shows what you've tried. This only shows that you've created the `textarea`s and a `button`. Can you show what you have of the `valthisform()` definition?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you but I did add some more information. Thank you for any help you may provide.